# unable to format usb drive

Tags: partition, usb, usb-drive, fdisk, gparted

I'm trying to read an usb drive that until a few day ago seemed to be perfectly working.
Today windows started to be unable to access or modify its content. Trying to reformat it with linux (arch distribution) there are a few strange things.
The output of lsblk is *(sdc is the faulty usb drive)*

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk 
  sda1   8:1    0 149.1G  0 part /
  sda2   8:2    0  1007K  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
  sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /mnt/toshibaExt
sdc      8:32   1     8M  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The output of lsblk -f is:

```
# lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                            
  sda1 ext4               5711fd14-4c90-487f-a8fc-ae7923d54dc5 /
  sda2                                                         
sdb                                                            
  sdb1 ntfs   TOSHIBA EXT 5ADEC4FBDEC4D085                     /mnt/toshibaExt
sdc                                                            
sr0
```

Trying to erase the content with dd results in

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc
dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdc’: No space left on device
16385+0 records in
16384+0 records out
8388608 bytes (8.4 MB) copied, 1.07083 s, 7.8 MB/s
```

Trying to create a new partition table with gparted,
gparted sees in sdc a single chunk of unallocated memory of 8MiB, with

```
Partition=unallocated,
File System=unallocated
Size=8.00 MiB
Used=---
Unused=---
Flags=
```

If i try to create a new partition table from gparted, msdos type, no error is given in the gui but nothing seems to happen. In the terminal i have a "/dev/sdc: unrecognised disk label" error. Trying to create a new partition results in the error message: "no partition table found".

With fdisk, i tried to create a new partition with

```
#fdisk /dev/sdc
n p <enter> <enter> w
```

It says that a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 7 MiB has been created, but trying again with lsblk or gparted nothing seems to have changed.

EDIT:

The output of dmesg after plugging in the USB is:

```
[  931.543277] usb 5-7: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  931.668457] usb-storage 5-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  931.669171] scsi6 : usb-storage 5-7:1.0
[  932.670552] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk 2.0   2.60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  932.671782] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 16384 512-byte logical blocks: (8.38 MB/8.00 MiB)
[  932.672412] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  932.672419] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[  932.673030] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  932.673036] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  932.677671]  sdc: unknown partition table
[  932.680661] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

EDIT2:
Output of fdisk -l:

```
$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdc -l

Disk /dev/sdc: 8 MiB, 8388608 bytes, 16384 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Comment: So gparted sees the correct device, right?  And it is unmounted?  In gparted, are you writing a new table (Device>Create Partition Table), writing over the unallocated sector, and then applying?  And no errors?! And as a word of advice, you don't need to copy `/dev/zero` to the device.  Gparted, fdisk, cfdisk, whatever will write over the old partition and write a new table for you.

Comment: What does `dmesg` say about this device while you're accessing it?

Comment: @StevenWalton gparted sees the device. The device is unmounted (I don't think I couldn't mount it anyway as there is no partition in it). I suspected that dd was useless, but it striked me the "no space left on device" message. Is that normal behavior in this circumstances?
When I try to create the partition table (by Device->Create Partition Table) it seems to work for a few seconds, then it stops without error messages in the GUI and with the only "unrecognized partition table" msg in the terminal. The apply button is still disabled.

Comment: @slm added to the post the output of dmesg

Comment: @glance - sorry what does dmesg show after you access the device? This looks like what it shows just after you physically connect it to the computer.

Comment: @slm what do you mean by "access the device"? I cannot mount it, so I cannot access its content. When I try to create a partition table on it the only message that comes out in dmesg is "sdc: unknown partition table". Did you mean this kind of "access"?

Comment: @glance - yes I wanted to see if there were any msgs being thrown in `dmesg` when you attempted to access it. Can you please include the output of `sudo fdisk -l`?

Comment: @slm done. The USB is still detected as an 8 MiB device, while it clearly should have more storage space. Does this mean I'm dealing with hardware corruption? The device is basically new.

Comment: @glance gparted won't let the apply button be clickable unless you have a partition table on it AND are trying to apply a format (ie, FAT32) to it.  As for the small space, this is normal.  Don't fret.  If you ever make a live usb you'll see this happen.  It's fine.  I'm at a loss, sorry.  But I suspect people will tell you that it is hardware corruption, and I'll tell you that this is unlikely. Best is to try another formatting tool like cfdisk or just brute till you're done. If I think of anything I'll come back.

Comment: A basically new 8MB usb drive? In 2014?

Comment: @DarioP as I said above, the usb drive has NOT 8MB of storage space, it should have a few GB.

Comment: The size may be shown to be less than the actual, but the fact that dd stops copying at 8 MB to me seems pretty much a hardware defect. Try to `dd` as you did but passing `-bs=16M` as option (this force it to read and write blocks of 16MB). Should it fail I would take the drive back to the store...